# Using regex to change sub element image from off to on and back

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

In an effort to keep code down I was hoping to use regular expressions with jQuery to switch the on and off states inside a hover for an image.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href=""><img src="images/nav_first_off.png" /></a>
    <ul class="sub_menu sub1"><li>
      <div class="topnav_dropdown_left"><a href=""><img src="images/topnav_dropdown_first.jpg" /></a></div>
    </li></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="images/nav_second_off.png" /></a>
    <ul class="sub_menu sub2"><li>
      <div class="topnav_dropdown_left"><a href=""><img src="images/topnav_dropdown_second.jpg" /></a></div>
    </li></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="images/nav_third_off.png" /></a>
    <ul class="sub_menu sub3"><li>
      <div class="topnav_dropdown_left"><a href=""><img src="images/topnav_dropdown_third.jpg" /></a></div>
    </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So with using the hover function above changing the subsequent nav_first_off.png, nav_second_off.png with the li hover and using the regex to cut the _off.png and switch to _on.png.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks for even looking.

Comment: Duplicate question, this question with answer exists on StackOverflow.

Comment: ehm... where? A reference would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function into [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change the `src` attribute, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");});
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('a img', this).attr('src', function(i, src) { 
      return src.replace('_off','_on'); 
    });
 }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('a img', this).attr('src', function(i, src) { 
      return src.replace('_on','_off'); 
    });
  });
});
```

In the function, the `src` parameter in `function(i, src)` is the old `src` value, so we're just doing a [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/replace) on that, you can pass it a more complicated regex if needed as well.

Comment: Works like a charm! 

Thanks I always try not to use regex as for the speed hit, but wasn't sure on that and I was over-thinking the selector.

Comment: @Chris - Welcome :)  Make sure to accept answers on this and future questions via the check-mark beside the one that helped!